# cvflann problem in rgbdslamv2

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-hydro, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, Endres!

your rgbdslam pkg in ros fuerte is very good.

and it was good working in my ros fuerte.

But I had to upgrade ros version

So, I use your rgbdslam v2 in Hydro

and I have some problem in cvflann, kdtree_index

I commanded following in terminal

```
roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch
```

I got this error log

```
Initializing Node...
[ INFO] [1406691638.675684807]: Connected to roscore
[ INFO] [1406691638.928690303]: Listening to /camera/rgb/image_color and /camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
[ INFO] [1406691638.928774911]: SIFTGPU is to be used
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Save Octomap" under id 6 
[ INFO] [1406691639.270821874]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1406691639.271024653]: 1. device on bus 003:06 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00366807039049A'
[ INFO] [1406691639.272253065]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1406691639.321850205]: Opened 'SensorV2' on bus 3:6 with serial number 'A00366807039049A'
[ INFO] [1406691639.688903629]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1406691639.688985773]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1406691639.692854115]: Camera calibration file /home/administrator/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00366807039049A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1406691639.692920806]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1406691639.692997875]: Camera calibration file /home/administrator/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00366807039049A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1406691639.693043348]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1406691644.266119473]: First RGBD-Data Received
[ INFO] [1406691645.071752195]: Depth and RGB image off more than 1/30sec: 987669918 (nsec)
[ INFO] [1406691646.009873741]: Pause toggled to: false
[ INFO] [1406691648.795465700]: Caught feature with zero in depth neighbourhood
[ INFO] [1406691648.801984358]: Feature Descriptors size: 65 x 128
[ INFO] [1406691648.802126517]: Feature Count of Node:  65
[ INFO] [1406691648.809551670]: Ground Truth Transform for First Node: Translation 0 0 0
[ INFO] [1406691648.809608380]: Ground Truth Transform for First Node: Rotation 0 0 0 1
[ INFO] [1406691648.809651525]: Adding initial node with id 0 and seq 0, v_id: 0
[ INFO] [1406691648.811384037]: Setting Renderable
[ INFO] [1406691648.813476929]: Depth and RGB image off more than 1/30sec: 55837044 (nsec)
[ INFO] [1406691648.815479907]: 1 Keyframes: 0, 
[ INFO] [1406691648.998745941]: Feature Descriptors size: 64 x 128
[ INFO] [1406691648.998854778]: Feature Count of Node:  64
[ INFO] [1406691649.001442715]: Odometry Delta: Translation 0 0 0
[ INFO] [1406691649.001505677]: Odometry Delta: Rotation 0 0 0 1
[ INFO] [1406691649.001543844]: No Valid Odometry, using identity
[ INFO] [1406691649.001617167]: Node ID's to compare with candidate for node 1. Sequential: 0
[ INFO] [1406691649.001670154]: Nodes to compare: 0
[ INFO] [1406691649.001722422]: Running node comparisons in parallel in 3 (of 4) available threads
rgbdslam: /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20140617-1410/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/kdtree_index.h:458: void cvflann::KDTreeIndex<Distance>::getNeighbors(cvflann::ResultSet<typename Distance::ResultType>&, const ElementType*, int, float) [with Distance = cvflann::L2<float>, typename Distance::ResultType = float, cvflann::KDTreeIndex<Distance>::ElementType = float]: Assertion `result.full()' failed.
================================================================================REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-22] has died!
process has died [pid 19176, exit code -6, cmd /home/administrator/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/administrator/.ros/log/1049609e-1791-11e4-b20f-c8f733a05ad2/rgbdslam-22.log].
log file: /home/administrator/.ros/log/1049609e-1791-11e4-b20f-c8f733a05ad2/rgbdslam-22*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
```

anyone getting this error, please, answer me.
thx:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188269/cvflann-problem-in-rgbdslamv2/) by [dlxhrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7521/dlxhrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Felix
I have the same problem too.
I just downloaded the RGBDSLAM v2.  after running  "roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch" command a GUI comes up . it can identify  some features with blue circle around , but after hitting Space or Enter for 2 or 3 times that error appears. as i just downloaded the  RGBDSLAM v2 , it should be the Bug-Fixed one.... So i don`t know whats the problem ... I appreciate if you could Help me ... Thanks

Mohammad Reza :)

---

Originally posted by [Mohammad Reza](https://answers.ros.org/users/20253/mohammad-reza/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is weird. The assertion only happens if the feature searched for is a zero vector, which shouldn't happen. There was a bug that caused this, but I fixed it (sometime in May or earlier), so if you haven't updated in months, you should try that. Otherwise try using SURF. If you could, please send me a short dataset that lets me reproduce this problem.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2